# how to use iTextSharp with existing wpf document?

Tags: wpf, itext

I have a existing wpf document,
how do I get an pdf via iTextSharp from this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, which is easy, but probably not the most efficient way is to render the WPF document to an image and then embed the image in a PDF using iTextSharp.

I have done it this way before successfully. Initially I tried to convert the control primitives (shapes) to PDF equivalents, but this proved too hard.